# Views content not showing on switching to other tabs using TabbedView of SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabbed-view

I'm implementing `TabbedView` using `SwiftUI` framework by referring https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview

When running on the simulator, only the first tab view contents showing and other tabs contents not showing. Even after restarting XCode, simulator etc.

App video link: https://youtu.be/Gibu8jfQQ5I

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
         TabbedView {
            Text("The First Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text("First")
            }
            Text("Another Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("Second")
            }
            Text("The Last Tab")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
                    Text("Third")
            }
        }.font(.headline)
    }
}
```

Appreciate you help and suggestions!

Comment: try to add `.padding()` to `TabbedView `.

Comment: Hmmm, I used the same code and it worked well for me on the simulator and the preview tab. I'm using beta 5. You could also try removing and adding back the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In beta 5, your code works, and also `TabbedView` was renamed to `TabView`. If you cannot upgrade to beta 5 yet, to fix your problem in beta 4, you need to add `.tag(n)` to each view:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
         TabbedView {
            Text("The First Tab").tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.square.fill")
                    Text("First")
            }
            Text("Another Tab").tag(2)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "2.square.fill")
                    Text("Second")
            }
            Text("The Last Tab").tag(3)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "3.square.fill")
                    Text("Third")
            }
        }.font(.headline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't show the tabs under the "more" tab. So tabs 5, 6, 7, etc. Looks like a bug to me.